# How to avoid showing a notification in service worker push event

Tags: javascript, firebase, service-worker

Im currently working in an app who already generates a popup message, so i want to listen a push notification in background with firebase, but i want only to pass some data to the client, and avoid showing a message from service worker. I already try different way, but all of them show the custom popup from google "this site has been updated in the background".
Now my code is working as expected, but i dont like the idea of waiting a null promise. There is a better solution?, what are the risks of using this aproach. I didnt found much information about event.waitUntil(), i dont know how much it waits, for example. Any help is welcome. (I already tried all of this https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/126)

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    if(event.data) {
        const listenerEvent = event.data.text();
        const response = JSON.parse(listenerEvent);
        var promiseChain = null;
        const bc = new BroadcastChannel('firebase_background_message_channel');
        bc.postMessage(response);
        event.waitUntil(promiseChain);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome shows the "This site has been updated in the background." notification when a push message is received and the push event in the service worker does not show a notification after the promise passed to `event.waitUntil()` has finished.

Chrome requires that a notification is shown when a push message is received to prevent sites from draining the users battery by sending a lots of quiet push messages.

There's more info on this in [Handling Push Events](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/handling-messages).